# phonegap android datepicker plugin not working on second field

Tags: android, html, plugins, cordova, datepicker

```
$('.nativedatepicker').focus(function(event) {
var currentField = $(this);
var myNewDate = Date.parse(currentField.val()) || new Date();
if(typeof myNewDate === "number") {
myNewDate = new Date (myNewDate);
}

            // Same handling for iPhone and Android
            window.plugins.datePicker.show({
                date : myNewDate,
                mode : 'date', // date or time or blank for both
                allowOldDates : true
            }, function(returnDate) {
                var newDate = new Date(returnDate);
                currentField.val(newDate.toString("dd/MMM/yyyy"));

                // This fixes the problem you mention at the bottom of this script with it not working a second/third time around, because it is in focus.
                currentField.blur();
            });
        });
```

I have two inputs

I have inserted this could but the datepicker then stops working after selecting second field
Please help

Comment: Hi here is the plugin link https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/DatePicker